# About 2dnav using nav2djs with Turtlebot and compatible packages

Tags: ros, turtlebot, tutorial, nav2d, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working in a project  integrates the web_video_server with map navigation capability, I have the following questions about the packages:

For the use of nav2djs:

1. The example that is in the webpage [nav2djs tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2djs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicNav2DWidget) is for the robot pr2, can I use the same launch files for the Turtlebot? If it is possible which would be the first step to take?

For the navigation using rviz:

2. I noticed that the web_video_server cannot run together with the amcl_demo.launch of this [tutortial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map)  because there are dependencies for the camara node, there is a way to use both of them but without the topic block restriction?
   (I cannot use map_server like in the nav2djs tutorial, because the Turtlebot Autonomuos navigation gives conflicts with this too).

Thanks beforehand!

Update:
Like @rtoris288 said, the integration of the stack navigation and using the camera for streaming images is possible, the solution is running/launching the following nodes:

3dsensor
map_server
amcl
move_base
robot_pose_publisher
web_video_server

So, using 3dsensor instead the openni launch file (that I was launching before), bring all the topics and nodes that are needed to make both functionalities work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205266/about-2dnav-using-nav2djs-with-turtlebot-and-compatible-packages/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. `nav2djs` will work with any robot that utilizes the [standard navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) which [includes the turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation). You would need to [change the name of the server](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2djs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicNav2DWidget#CA-de220fe09711c67ac0cd08ad32aa55a95bd61ec2_34) to match that of the turtlebot and launch the turtlebot's navigation nodes (not sure which they are I don't use the turtlebot), `robot_pose_publisher`, and `rosbridge_websocket` as defined in the tutorial.
2. I see no reason `web_video_server` can't launch with `amcl_demo`. Multiple ROS nodes can utilize the same topics without any 'dependency' issues. That's one of the core beauties of ROS! :) If you try and launch the node twice (e.g., if amcl already launched `map_server`), then you don't need to launch it again since it is already running.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-19**:
About number 2, if I am using`openni.launch` that launchs the camera node that uses `web_video_server`, I can't launch the `3dsensor.launch` file because it remaps the names of the topics, when I try to launch the `openni` and then the `3dsensor`  in that order, there is no web_video_streaming

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-26**:
How can I remap the nodes using a launch file? I think that maybe the way to go is: Analysing which nodes differs between the application desired and the one already done, then launch the missing nodes and remap to integrate, what do you think?